# How can you modify a SUBSET-SUM instance so evaluating a set outputs either 0 or 1?

Tags: np-complete, subset-sum

An SUBSET-SUM *instance* is a list of $n$ integers $\{ a_1, a_2,... a_n\}$. To *evaluate* a subset is to output the sum of a subset.

However, I want to know, is it possible to create a new instance $T$, the same size as the original set $S$, that any subset in $S$ that evaluates to $W$, the corresponding subset in $T$ (the numbers taken from the same positions) evaluates to $0$? All other subsets in $T$ should evaluate to $1$.

Bonus: Give a list of other NP-complete problems (other than 3SAT, where you evaluate a *formula* that either outputs $0$ or $1$ depending on the set of binary variables being passed into it), where evaluating an analogous instance outputs $0$ if it satisfies some objective related to the problem and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: I'm confused by this question.  I don't know what you mean by "find the sum of a selection of numbers in the set"; which numbers?  Is it possible to modify an instance?  Sure, you can do whatever you want.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @D.W. 1. For example, take a set $\{3,4,5,6\}$. Evaluating a set could mean finding the sum of a particular selection of numbers in the set, like $\{3,4\}$ or just $\{3\}$. 
2. I'm asking that for any particular set (the $n$th set could be defined as you'll like, the most common is to take a number $n$, convert it to binary, and sum the numbers whose positions correspond with $1$s), can you adjust the instance that for a weight $W$, the output of a set would be $0$ iff the sum of the corresponding set equals $W$, and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: "Evaluating" is pretty unclear language.  Are you asking: given a set $S$ and a target $W$, find a new set $T$ so that there exists a subset of $S$ that sums to $W$ iff there exists a subset of $T$ that sums to 0?

Comment: @D.W. Yes, and the second part is that all other subsets of $S$ that *don't* add to $W$, the corresponding set in $T$ should sum to $1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding"?  Are you requiring $T$ to have the same size as $S$?  Do you require not just "existence" but also that the subset of $T$ that sums to 0 has to be the "same" subset of $S$ that sums to $W$?  None of these requirements are stated in the question.  Don't force us to guess -- your question needs to be clear enough that everyone can understand what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W. Ok, I made some edits to hopefully make my question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I want to know, is it possible to create a new instance T, the same size as the original set S, that any subset in S that evaluates to W, the corresponding subset in T (the numbers taken from the same positions) evaluates to 0? All other subsets in T should evaluate to 1.

No, this is impossible. Consider $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and $W=3$. Our set $T$ should be $\{a,b,c\}$ such that $a+b=0, c=0$ and $a+b+c=1$.